# What is difference in AWS lambda and AWS lambda proxy?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS. I know it could a very layman question.
but I am trying to pass and accept the parameters in AWS lambda proxy. I was able to do it in AWS lambda using `body mapping` template, Is there any way in which i can get the `queryString` we map in AWS lambda in Lambda proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Lambda Proxy, API Gateway maps the entire client request to the input event parameter of the backend lambda function as follows.

```
{
   "resource": "Resource path",
   "path": "Path parameter",
   "httpMethod": "Incoming request's method name"
   "headers": {Incoming request headers}
   "queryStringParameters": {query string parameters }
   "pathParameters":  {path parameters}
   "stageVariables": {Applicable stage variables}
   "requestContext": {Request context, including authorizer-returned key-value pairs}
   "body": "A JSON string of the request payload."
   "isBase64Encoded": "A boolean flag to indicate if the applicable request payload is Base64-encode"}
```

Refer Setup Proxy Integration [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format) of AWS.

Here is a [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html) of how to parse the event data such as query string.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to access the my endpoint using 'path' variable

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using serverless framework to develop and deploy lambdas and API gateway, then there is a different way to configure the API gateway as AWS lambda proxy using open API specification aka Swagger! Please see the following example of the configuration.

```html
resources:
  Resources:
    SupportProxy:
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
      Properties:
        Name: lambda-proxy
        Description: "The API proxy entry point."
        Body:
          swagger: '2.0'
          info:
            version: '2016-09-12T23:19:28Z'
            title: ProxyResource
          basePath: /myapp
          schemes:
            - https
          # Work-around to prevent API Gateway from trying to re-encode binary files (images, fonts, etc) as unicode text.
          x-amazon-apigateway-binary-media-types:
            - '*/*'
          paths:
            /myapp/service1/{proxy+}:
              x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
                parameters:
                  - name: proxy
                    in: path
                    required: true
                    type: string
                responses: {}
                x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                  responses:
                    default:
                      statusCode: '200'
                  requestParameters:
                    integration.request.path.proxy: method.request.path.proxy
                  uri: ${service1.url}/{proxy}
                  passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
                  httpMethod: ANY
                  type: http_proxy
```